# the bucket hashing if has same value,which will be take out?

Tags: hash, hashtable

The HashTable is stored in bucket hashing,

when store more than two same hashing values, if take out,which will be take out?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the hash table implementation. In java's HashTable / HashMap implementations, both are stored, if `object.equals()` indicates the objects are not equal.  If `object.equals()` returns true (the objects are considered equal), the last one added is what's stored.